# Looping in R with tidyverse

Tags: loops, csv, tidyverse

I am trying to read multiple csv files with date in the format dd-mm-yyyy. I want to convert the months into seasons, for which I have used the following codes (for one csv file):

```
x= data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(year = lubridate::year(UDATE), 
                month = lubridate::month(UDATE), 
                day = lubridate::day(UDATE))

x %>% 
  mutate(season = case_when(
    month %in% c('3', '4', '5', '6') ~ 'Summer',
    month  %in% c('7', '8', '9', '10') ~ 'Monsoon',
    month  %in% c('11', '12', '1', '2') ~ 'Winter'
  ))
```

Now I want to run this for the multiple csv files simultaneously and export those files with the converted data frames such that my month is converted into seasons.

Can someone please suggest me how to put that in a loop function for multiple csv files simultaneously.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Without data to reproduce it is a little hard to help, so I wrote some generic code that might need a few tweaks to solve your problem.

First, I would create a single function that import, transform and export the data.

```
prep_data <-
  function(file_name){
  data <-
    read.csv2(file_name) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(
      year = lubridate::year(UDATE), 
      month = lubridate::month(UDATE), 
      day = lubridate::day(UDATE),
      season = case_when(
        month  %in% c('3', '4', '5', '6') ~ 'Summer',
        month  %in% c('7', '8', '9', '10') ~ 'Monsoon',
        month  %in% c('11', '12', '1', '2') ~ 'Winter'
      ) 
  #I put "_new" as prefix to not overwrite the original .csv         
  write.csv2(file = paste0("new_",file_name))            
}
```

Then I would create a vector with all my files names.

```
all_files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv",path = "your path with the csv files",full.names = TRUE)
```

Lastly, apply the function for all files.

```
purrr::map(.x = all_files,.f = prep_data)
```

Comment: In the prep data for file_name do I have to add my file or just remain it as it is?  head of my data is like this:                                                                                                                 
No CollarID UDATE UTIME
279 37528 19-06-2019 7:30:39 AM
While running the whole code it showed this error:                                                                    Error in `dplyr::mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `year = lubridate::year(UDATE)`.
Caused by error in `lubridate::year()`:
! object 'UDATE' not found

Comment: Is the variable UDATE present in all your files?

Comment: yes the variable is present in all the files. UDATE represent date and I want to add a column with season corresponding to each month of each row.

Comment: I first converted the date format using code `linelist <- data %>%
  mutate(date_onset = lubridate::dmy(data$UDATE))`

Comment: OK, so that is what is missing my code. I recommend that you create a script for a single file with all the transformation desired, than adpat to my code to apply to all files

Comment: Okay, Thak you so much for the help.